# c# add items in a listbox from annother class

Tags: c#, class, listbox

I want to add items in the listbox in form1 from class "add", but as I did it it doesn't work. Please, help!
My code:

```
namespace Server_Virtual_Server_Programm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }


    }
    pulic class Add 
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("test"); //i want somthing that work like this, because so it doesn't work xD
    }
}
```

Comment: Call  that Add in your form load and it will be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems in your code.
Firstly you should assign a name to your listbox :

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

Then you should write tour code inside a function not in the class.

```
    public static class ListBoxAdder
    {
        public static void Add(ListBox listbox, string newItem)
        {
            listbox.Items.Add(newItem);
        }
    }
```

using this class :

```
ListBoxAdder.Add(listBox1, "first");
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Just call  `Add()` in constructor:

```
namespace Server_Virtual_Server_Programm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listBox1.Items.Add("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, so it works, but i have a server with mutiple clients and i want to use the listbox as a "console" so it show when a client connected - the client accept is in annother class ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in the **Form1** class which will be called to update the listbox.
This method would do the trick:

```
 public void UpdateList(string value)
 {
     listBox1.Items.Add(value);
 }
```

Then you could easily call the method from your class.

Good luck.